# get intune device ID on user's device to query device info filtered with device-id

Tags: windows, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I have a website that would need to access information maintained in Intune using graph API for the device accessing this website. I would have the proper token and permission to fire a query on GraphAPI and get the response for the particular device. however, I don't know how my website would have this device ID. Is there a way to know the Intune device ID of the machine in the browser?